# Are there pre-paid SIM cards in Canada with big data offerings?

Tags: canada, internet

What is the best offer for a pre-paid SIM card with big data? I don't need to make a voice calls or send SMS. I'll need it for two weeks only.

I'm going to Toronto and then I want to visit PEI (via Quebec, Montreal).

Comment: That linked question is a good resource, but also note that Canada is a huge country, and Canada has some regional providers, so where exactly you are going to go in Canada is going to be a major consideration in what provider you would use.

Comment: You'll be most interested in Rogers, Bell and Telus, then, and the MVNOs (virtual networks) that use one of these three networks.  There are other providers that cover some of the places you'll be, but only these three cover all of the places you'll be.